# How can I create a dictionary from inputs using forEach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, foreach

I want to create a dictionary in javascript. I have some dynamic inputs that have different attributes and I would like to create a dictionary from those inputs and attributes how can I do this?

My html looks something like this:

```
<div class="margin_bot" id="itemRows1">
  <p id="ProwNum1">
     <input class="params margin_bot input_text input_size text_input span-11" tipo="LAM" type="text" name="par_1" value="password" placeholder="Valor">
     <input class="params margin_bot input_text input_size text_input span-11" tipo="LAM" type="text" name="par_2" value="password2" placeholder="Valor"> 
  </p>
</div>
```

And my javacript function looks like this:

```
function create_kapps_dict(selector, content){
var items = $('p[id^="ProwNum"]').find('.params').filter(':visible');
var post_settings = [];
items.forEach( )
}
```

But it's not working. What I'm trying to do is create a dictionary as the key be the `name` and the values be the `tipo` and the `value` of the input.

Comment: Also, to invoke a function you have to do `functionName(anyParametersItNeeds)`.  But your last line is not doing that.

Comment: jQuery seems redundant. Also using id for selecting seems a bit odd. Certainly for a div with `1` meaning there could be more so it's not dynamic. The `post_settings` is overwritten each pass so only 1 variable will be stored. Also this variable isn;t available outside the function. As Taplar mentioned you don't call a function as if it is an array. Using fat arrow functions needs es6 handler if you want it to work in IE

Comment: There's more inputs I just didn't add them all, I just added the first one just to show the context

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your js a bit (removed the jquery). 
Check out the attached code pen for the full example.
Its not the same as a dictionary in say c# but it is an object where you can access values based on the name of the element. 
https://codepen.io/tstrand66/pen/vzNLQe?editors=1011

```
function create_kapps_dict(content) {
    const post_settings = {};
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.params')).forEach(function 
    (element) {
        post_settings[element.getAttribute('name')] = element.getAttribute(content);
    });
    console.log(post_settings);
    return post_settings;
}
const createKappsDict = create_kapps_dict('tipo');
console.log(createKappsDict['par_1']);
console.log(createKappsDict['par_2']);
const createKappsDict2 = create_kapps_dict('value');
console.log(createKappsDict2['par_1']);
console.log(createKappsDict2['par_2']);
```